# Notification, Activity

Tags: android, activity, android-notification

В `MainActivity` совершается некоторый процесс в фоновом потоке, при достижении определенного условия, необходимо запустить `BreakActivity`, в `Intent` кладу строку, которую необходимо отобразить в `BreakActivity`. Уведомление работает частично: появляется, но при клике закрывается приложение. Иконка не отображается, ни маленькая, ни большая (читал, что большая автоматически из маленькой растягивается).
Если необходим код активностей - дополню.

Вот код уведомления:

```
private void doNotification() {
    Log.v(TAG, "MainActivity doNotification");
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, com.hfad.test1.BreakActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("task", etName.getText().toString());
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);
    builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.tomato)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
            .setTicker("Перерыв!")
            .setContentTitle("Передохни!")
            .setContentText("Настало время отдыха.");

    Notification notification = builder.build();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(101, notification);
}
```

Вот лог ошибки:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.hfad.test1, PID: 12550
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.hfad.test1/com.hfad.test1.BreakActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2346)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2408)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5277)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:919)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:714)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
at com.hfad.test1.BreakActivity.onCreate(BreakActivity.java:49)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5983)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2299)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2408) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5277) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:919) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:714)
```

В логах почему-то не отображается запись `"MainActivity doNotification"`. Пробовал ставить ее и в конце и кода, и в начале. Все равно, отображается лог, который расположен в вызывающем месте, сразу после метода `doNotification`.

Comment: BreakActivity.java строка 49. Там у вас ошибка, все остальное роли не играет.

Comment: `Intent intent = getIntent();
 String name = intent.getExtras().getString("task");
 tvName.setText(name);`

Видимо ошибка при передаче данных в интенте. Может при уведомлении данные иначе передаются?

Comment: Убрал вообще передачу данных в интенте, ошибка осталась.

Comment: Попробуйте добавить action для intent'а, без него говорят extras не передаются.

Comment: Согласно ошибке `Bundle` у вас `null` в интенте. Попробуйте вот так вытаскивать: `intent.getStringExtra("task");` Т.е. напрямую из интента, а не из его bundle

Comment: @ЮрийСПб http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/content/Intent.java#Intent.getStringExtra%28java.lang.String%29 просто null вернется, проблема в интенте.

Comment: @YuraIvanov, я знаю, что там должна быть встроена защита "от дурака", но, вроде, я когда-то встречал некоторые различия в `getStringExtra()` и `getExtras().getString()`

Comment: Возможно, интент не передаётся, а используется старый, попробуйте флаги в интент добавить: `notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)`

Comment: `getStringExtra` подошло, отлично. Достает текст из интента. Осталось разобраться почему не выводит картинку вместо стандартной. Когда лежит в `mipmap` - ругается и не запускается, перекинул в `drawable` - скомпилировалось и запустилось, но картинка стандартный зеленый андроид.

Comment: Хм, видимо дело в устройстве, попробовал запустить на другом - все работает. На моем же не отображает иконки и виджеты кнопки, если расположены один рядом с другим, почему-то слитны. Это может как-то изменяется в устройстве?

Comment: @morethanfish, если ответ мой помог, то можете отметить его верным. Если есть другие вопросы - задавайте отдельный вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно ошибке Bundle у вас null в интенте. Попробуйте вот так вытаскивать:

```
   intent.getStringExtra("task");
```

Т.е. напрямую из интента, а не из его bundle

---

Также, возможно, интент не передаётся, а используется старый, попробуйте флаги в интент добавить:

```
notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)
```